# Delete From table ; ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01031

I have a table with only one field: `id_acteur_fk`.

When I want to delete a line by this request ;

```
DELETE gros_postes WHERE id_acteur_fk = '325'
```

I get this error :

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `gros_postes` doesn't belong to you, and its owner didn't grant `delete` privilege to you (or public) so you aren't allowed to remove any rows. What to do? Contact the owner and ask for some more privileges.

As you aren't referencing it (`gros_postes`) with owner name, then it might be a (public) synonym, or maybe a (materialized?) view.

---

Provide some more info if what I wrote doesn't help. For example, what does

```
select * from all_objects where object_name = 'GROS_POSTES';
```

return?